# Can replace a tag I accidentally created?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I tried to tag a post "Flint's", and I got "flint" and "s" instead. I tried to delete the tags and enter "flints", but Stack Exchange says it's too close to "flint" and won't let me do it.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the tag is easy; just remove it from [your question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/108583/36324), and the system will [automatically clean it up within 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40724/295232).

I guess that after that period, you could create a [flints](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flints) tag, but should you? A tag for a single brand is IMHO much too narrow; I couldn't find a precedent for this (but maybe, as a Dutch person, I don't recognize a brand). This is what the [Help Center](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) says about creating tags:

> #### When should I create new tags?
>
> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question *does* cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

The [barbecue-sauce](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/barbecue-sauce) tag is already focused enough, and tags aren't the only way to find questions; even without the [flint](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flint) tag, your question will be found when people search for the word "flint's".

Comment: Thanks Glorfindel!